# Trying to add a bunch of action listeners

Tags: java

I'm trying to give my buttons all their own action listener but I keep getting a weird error

"No enclosing instance of type Buttons is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Buttons (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Buttons)."

On the line where I add the first Action Listener.
Any solutions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Buttons
{
static int numPress = 0;
static int n = 0;
static int fromX;
static int fromY;
static int toX;
static int toY;
static JButton button[] = new JButton[15];
static int[][] mult = new int[][]
        {
            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        };

public static void main(String []args)
{
    pegGame game = new pegGame();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Button");
    int row = 5;
    int size = 50;
    for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            button[n] = new JButton();
            button[n].setBounds((size*row/2 + i*size - j*size/2),size*j - size,size,size);
            f.add(button[n]);
            numPress++;
            n++;
        }
    }
    bttnTxt();

    button[0].addActionListener(new btn0());
    button[1].addActionListener(new btn1());
    button[2].addActionListener(new btn2());
    button[3].addActionListener(new btn3());
    button[4].addActionListener(new btn4());
    button[5].addActionListener(new btn5());
    button[6].addActionListener(new btn6());
    button[7].addActionListener(new btn7());
    button[8].addActionListener(new btn8());
    button[9].addActionListener(new btn9());
    button[10].addActionListener(new btn10());
    button[11].addActionListener(new btn11());
    button[12].addActionListener(new btn12());
    button[13].addActionListener(new btn13());
    button[14].addActionListener(new btn14());

    f.setSize(row*size,row*size);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
class btn0 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 0;
            fromY = 0;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 0;
            toY = 0;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn1 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 0;
            fromY = 1;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 0;
            toY = 1;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn2 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 1;
            fromY = 1;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 1;
            toY = 1;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn3 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 0;
            fromY = 2;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 0;
            toY = 2;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn4 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 1;
            fromY = 2;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 1;
            toY = 2;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn5 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 2;
            fromY = 2;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 2;
            toY = 2;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn6 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 0;
            fromY = 3;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 0;
            toY = 3;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn7 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 1;
            fromY = 3;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 1;
            toY = 3;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn8 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 2;
            fromY = 3;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 2;
            toY = 3;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn9 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 3;
            fromY = 3;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 3;
            toY = 3;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn10 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 0;
            fromY = 4;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 0;
            toY = 4;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn11 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 1;
            fromY = 4;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 1;
            toY = 4;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn12 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 2;
            fromY = 4;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 2;
            toY = 4;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn13 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 3;
            fromY = 4;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 3;
            toY = 4;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}
class btn14 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) 
    {
        if(numPress == 0)
        {
            fromX = 4;
            fromY = 4;
            numPress++;
        } else{
            toX = 4;
            toY = 4;
            moveCheck(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
}

public static void moveCheck(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{
    if (mult[toX][toY] == 0 && mult[fromX][fromY] == 1)
    {
        if (fromX + 2 == toX && fromY + 2 == toY && mult[toX][toY] == 0 && mult[fromX + 1][fromY + 1] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[(fromX + 1)][(fromY + 1)] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        } else if(fromX - 2 == toX && fromY - 2 == toY && mult[fromX - 1][fromY - 1] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[(fromX - 1)][(fromY - 1)] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        } else if(fromX + 2 == toX && fromY == toY && mult[fromX + 1][fromY] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[fromX + 1][fromY] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        } else if(fromX - 2 == toX && fromY == toY && mult[fromX - 1][fromY] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[fromX - 1][fromY] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        }else if(fromY + 2 == toY && fromX == toX && mult[fromX][fromY + 1] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[fromX][fromY + 1] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        }else if(fromY - 2 == toY && fromX == toX && mult[fromX][fromY - 1] == 1)
        {
            mult[fromX][fromY] = 0;
            mult[fromX][fromY - 1] = 0;
            mult[toX][toY] = 1;
        }else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please pick a legal move");
        }
    }else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please pick a legal move");
    }
    bttnTxt();
    numPress = 0;
}
public static void bttnTxt()
{
    button[0].setText(Integer.toString(mult[0][0]));
    button[1].setText(Integer.toString(mult[0][1]));
    button[2].setText(Integer.toString(mult[1][1]));
    button[3].setText(Integer.toString(mult[0][2]));
    button[4].setText(Integer.toString(mult[1][2]));
    button[5].setText(Integer.toString(mult[2][2]));
    button[6].setText(Integer.toString(mult[0][3]));
    button[7].setText(Integer.toString(mult[1][3]));
    button[8].setText(Integer.toString(mult[2][3]));
    button[9].setText(Integer.toString(mult[3][3]));
    button[10].setText(Integer.toString(mult[0][4]));
    button[11].setText(Integer.toString(mult[1][4]));
    button[12].setText(Integer.toString(mult[2][4]));
    button[13].setText(Integer.toString(mult[3][4]));
    button[14].setText(Integer.toString(mult[4][4]));
}
public static boolean checkWin()
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mult.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < mult.length; j++)
        {
            if(mult[i][j] != 0)
            {
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 1)
    {
        count = 0;
    } else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win!");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your btn0 and other classes are *inner* classes and are not static, so they require an outer enclosing instance of the buttons class. Make these static or put the initialization code into an instance method of class buttons.